# Why "test 2>&1 | clip" doesn't work as my expect in windows console?

Tags: redirect, command-line, pipe, stdout, stderr

I wan't to get windows wrong command error msg into the clipboard and then paste to other place. I just type this in cmd window:

```
test 2>&1 | clip
```

And I see no error msg in console, so I supposed the stderr should be redirect as my expect. Unfortunately, I get nothing when I "paste" to notepad.

I know that "java" print its help info to stderr, so I tried the following command:

```
java 2>&1 | clip
```

It works right as my expect, I "paste" the help info into notepad successfully!

So, why my first command print nothing to stdout? Where does the error msg actually go?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an error message *from the command processor*, then you need to redirect *its* output.

So,

```
cmd 2>&1 /C "test" | clip
```

Places the following in the clipboard:

> 'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: Yes, your command works well. But why my first command doesn't work? I'm curious about that.

Comment: @TedWang - because you're redirecting the error output for the "test" program. **not** the error output "in general", or as shown above, the error output for `cmd`. Each process has its own set of input, output and error, and the message you wanted to capture wasn't being generated by the "test" program (since it never even starts)

Comment: \@Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you! I understand!.